# Text does not align centrally

Tags: html, css, text-align

For some reason, my text just wont get centrally aligned. It is a little to the left. Even when I do text-align: right, it does not go to the place where it should. Here's my HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="strapwrap">
<div id="strap">
<div id="menu"><span id="sub"><a href="./">Home</a></span> <span id="sub"><a href="plans">Plans</a></span><span id="sub"><a href="faq">FAQ</a></span></div>
<div id="logo">
<a href="./"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
</div>

</div>
</div><div id="container">
<div id="login_thingy">
//all the login form, and some content goes here, unfortunately, it does not get centrally aligned.
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my style.css

```
body{
margin: 0;
background-image: url('http://athile.net/library/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/grass02-300x300.png');
}
#strapwrap{
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}
a{
color: inherit;
text-decoration: inherit;
}
#strap{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
#menu{
font-size: 25px;
height: 75px;
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
word-spacing: 25px;
}
#sub:hover{
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;
}
#login_thingy{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 15px;
font-size: 35px;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle live example please.

Comment: There : http://jsfiddle.net/LTcc8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5aJG/1/)

Change your CSS to add/alter:

```
#container{
    text-align:center; /* new addition */
}
#login_thingy {
    width: 80%;
    display:inline-block; /* replace margin auto */
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

All you need is to set `text-align:center` on the parent element (`#container`) then `display:inline-block;` on the child (`#login_thingy`). You can then remove any use of `margin:auto`

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your div text inside `<p>`

```
<div id="login_thingy">
    <p>all the login form, and some content goes here, unfortunately, it does not get centrally aligned.</p>
</div>
```

*Side Note:* It's a good practice to **not** to place direct text content inside the `div`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta3B6/)

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Text nodes shouldn't be placed directly inside div element.

Comment: I agree but be wary..its not necessarily always true, `p` denotes `paragraph` which not all text may be marked by (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) `div` is just a generic element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#container{
text-align:center
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pc525/)

Comment: Missing a semi-colon mate.

Comment: @Michael no need of semi-colon if there is only one statement

Answer (score 0):

Apply fixed width to the contents of `login_thingy` div and add `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` to the contents of `login_thingy` div.

Like

```
<div id="login_thingy">
<div style="width:50%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">all the login form, and some content goes here, unfortunately, it does not get centrally aligned.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all HTML comments are like this: `<!-- TEXT HERE -->`
Second of all you code is wrong. In the CSS part you have type this:

```
#login_thingy{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Without a semicolon (`;`) at the end of `text-align: center;` which may be the reason you are getting this error. So the **correct** code is:

```
#login_thingy{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If that doesn't work, just use a normal header and put it inside a div if you wish. Like so:

```
<h2 id="login_thingy"> TEXT HERE </h2>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Damn, all of you guys don't know how CSS are interpreted ? You never need last semi-colon and bracket, but well, it's more safe to place them as you might add further rules.

Comment: You actually do need the last semicolon and bracket.. I also improved my answer so check it again.

Comment: No you don't. All CSS minimifiers delete last semicolons and the last bracket (of the whole file). Missing them do not occur an error. Will we play this game longer ?